How to enable bi-directional clipboard with Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop Sharing
I'm trying to use Desktop Sharing with Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop.
I'm connecting with the Windows Remote Desktop client.
I can connect and perform basic operations, but the clipboard is apparently not supported. That is essential for any productive use.
Windows Remote Desktop client to a Windows server does support the clipboard.
I found this (old) question, and have verified that "StartupPrograms"="rdpclip" is set.
Is there anything that needs to be configured in Ubuntu to enable the clipboard? Is there a different RDP client I should try in Windows that would support the clipboard to Ubuntu?

I found the setting in the Windows Client under Remote Desktop / Show Options / Local Resources tab.  Clipboard is disabled by default.
I'm still searching for an answer to my other question on keyboard mapping
